# How to convert a nested object into an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
inputJson = {
    "mn": {
        "mt1": 1,
        "mtop": 2,
        "ot1": 3
    },
    "ln": {
        "mt1": 4,
        "mtop": 5,
        "ot1": 6
    }
}

OutputArrayOfJson=[
     { rs: "mt1", mn: 1, ln: 4 },
     { rs: "mtop", mn: 2, ln: 5 },
     { rs: "ot1", mn: 3, ln: 6 }
]
```

- rs is hardcode Key.

I don't know why am having hard time doing this operation.

Comment: What you have is not JSON. JSON is a **language-independent, textual** data format, just like XML or CSV. You simply have a JavaScript object and want to convert it to an array.

Answer (score 1):

It is a conversion of javascript objects

```
inputJson = {
  "mn": {
    "mt1": 1,
    "mtop": 2,
    "ot1": 3
  },
  "ln": {
    "mt1": 4,
    "mtop": 5,
    "ot1": 6
  }
}

d = {};
for(var key1 in inputJson){ 
  for(var key2 in inputJson[key1]) { 
    if(!(key2 in d)){ 
      d[key2]={};
    } 
    d[key2][key1] = inputJson[key1][key2];
  }
}

v = []; 
for(var k in d){ 
  var o = {}; 
  o.rs=k; 
  for(var k2 in d[k]){ 
    o[k2] = d[k][k2]; 
  } 
  v.push(o);
}

//result is in v
```

note: the next time you should shown example code or not will help

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the **object** and push each root property inside an **array**:

```
var arr = [];

for (var p in inputJson){
  arr.push(inputJson[p]);
}

console.log(arr);
```